# SQL find overlapping appointments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to make a report that will determine if any clients (patient_id) have a duplicate appointment in our system. I have the fields of proc_chron (start time down to the second), proc_chron_end (end time down to the second), and proc_duration. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
select

patient_id,
attending_id,
proc_duration,
proc_chron,
proc_chron_end


from patient_clin_tran
where place_of_service not in ('23', '24', '25', '26')
and (proc_chron between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-01')
and billing_proc_code not in ('BHHMTH')
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what the output should be. Should it just list clients that have overlaps, or also what appointments actually overlap?

Comment: Why 3 columns (start, end and duration)? 2 is enough - now you risk data inconsistency!

Comment: You can move duration. I just included 3 where I wasn't sure what type of logic would be best. My end goal is to be able is to insert the query into a crystal report and from there group by patient_id and list the conflict below. That way I'll be able to see what attending need to be talked with for the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way would be to add a `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery in the `where` clause that limits the result to those appointments that overlap.

```
select
    patient_id,
    attending_id,
    proc_duration,
    proc_chron,
    proc_chron_end
from patient_clin_tran p    -- notice the table alias
where place_of_service not in ('23', '24', '25', '26')
and (proc_chron between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-01')
and billing_proc_code not in ('BHHMTH')

and case when exists (
    select 1 from patient_clin_tran 
    where patient_id = p.patient_id
      and attending_id <> p.attending_id
      and p.proc_chron < proc_chron_end 
     and p.proc_chron_end > proc_chron
) then 1 else 0 end = 1
order by p.patient_id, p.attending_id;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5527d/1) with some imaginary data.

This only checks for overlapping appointments with different `attending_id`. If you want to check for overlaps with the same attending then you would have to remove the `and attending_id <> p.attending_id` and instead add a condition that uniquely identifies each row so that appointments don't overlap with themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My end goal is to put this in a Crystal report our billing department can view where I'll group it by patient and under that group show the duplicate conflicts and who the two attending (staff) people are, so we can clarify.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

Comment: @JeremyMcDevitt Check the line `(proc_chron between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-01')` I accidentally added `,'02'` at the end (also at the line `billing_proc_code not in ('BHHMTH')`) Remove that and it should be fine. The query in the fiddle should be ok and I've fixed the answer too now.

Comment: This is real close, but it looks like due to our system which tracks stuff in hours we have situations where a 10 - 11 is a thing and an 11-12 is a thing which is showing up as a overlap which it technically is. Any idea on how to have it subtract a second from the end time? Sorry for being difficult with this.

Comment: @JeremyMcDevitt Change the last conditions in the subquery to `and p.proc_chron <= dateadd(second,-1,proc_chron_end)
  and dateadd(second,-1,p.proc_chron_end) >= proc_chron`
or change the `<=` and `>=` to `<` and `>`. Either should work.

Comment: Removing the ='s did it perfectly. Just doing some cross checking now. Trying to figure out why it won't let me do an Order By at the end of it, so it's easier to cross check.

Comment: I included a statement terminating `;` at the end. Just add the `order by` before that. I've updated the answer to include the order

Comment: Thank you so much. It's perfect now. I really appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

This would tell you where you have over lapping appointments:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  patient_id
  ,attending_id
  ,proc_duration
  ,proc_chron
  ,proc_chron_end
FROM patient_clin_tran
WHERE place_of_service NOT IN ('23', '24', '25', '26')
  AND proc_chron BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-09-01'
  AND billing_proc_code NOT IN ('BHHMTH'))
SELECT c1.*
FROM cte c1
  INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c1.patient_id = c2.patient_id
WHERE c2.proc_chron BETWEEN c1.proc_chron AND c1.proc_chron_end
  AND c2.proc_chron_end BETWEEN c1.proc_chron AND c1.proc_chron_end
  AND c1.attending_id != c2.attending_id
```

All I did was wrap your query in a common table expression and the join it with itself on the patient ID. The where clause then filters only appoints that overlap excluding the identical appointment.

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

I'm getting this for an error. Not sure what is wrong with the syntax with that AND.

Comment: Sorry my join condition had an AND instead of =, now corrected.

Comment: This code didn't appear to work and would show everything within the date range, but the other code offered did it. Thank you for taking the time to type that up.